How to transition from 'kubernetes.io/ingress.class' to 'spec.ingressClassName' in Kubernetes config to address deprecation warning?
Here's my code "ingress-service.yaml"
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
name: wso2-portals-ingress
annotations:
**kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"**
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "route"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-hash: "sha1"
spec:
tls:

- hosts:
  - api.am.wso2.com
    rules:
- host: api.am.wso2.com
  http:
  paths:
  - path: /
    pathType: Prefix
    backend:
    service:
    name: wso2-am-service
    port:
    number: 9443

"Where should I add 'spec.ingressClassName' in the correct way?"
"After adding 'spec.ingressClassName' in the annotations section, I encountered an error preventing deployment in Kubernetes."

It's a field named ingressClassName underneath spec:, not an annotation.

ingressClassName is not an annotation but a configuration in the ingress specification. Please refer [1] for more information. In the provided example, you can ingressClassName under spec section to achieve your requirement.
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: wso2-portals-ingress
annotations:
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "route"
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-hash: "sha1"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - api.am.wso2.com
  rules:
  - host: api.am.wso2.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: wso2-am-service
            port:
              number: 9443

[1] - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#the-ingress-resource
